# htop isn't returning CPU or memory usage!?

Tags: macos, terminal, htop

I think that **top** is great application to monitor a Linux system. I really like it, but **top** doesn't look so good on Mac. I know that Mac have a system monitor to do it, but I prefer using a terminal.

I have installed **htop** by running:

`brew install htop`.

Here is what it looks like:

```
PID USER     PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
    1 0          0   0     0     0     0 ?  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 (launchd)
   10 0          0   0     0     0     0 ?  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 (kextd)
   11 0          0   0     0     0     0 ?  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 (UserEventAgent)
   12 65         0   0     0     0     0 ?  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 (mDNSResponder)
```

The problem is that both **CPU** and **MEM** aren't returning the real values of either on my system.

Has anyone else experienced this?
Or, could some one point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

I have the same problem so I check the recipe.

```
$ brew edit htop
```

Then I check this part of the recipe:

```
def caveats; <<-EOS.undent
    For htop to display correctly all running processes, it needs to run as root.
    If you don't want to `sudo htop` every time, change the owner and permissions:
    cd #{bin}
    chmod 6555 htop
    sudo chown root htop
EOS
```

So just type `sudo htop` and you will see **CPU** and **MEM**.

Comment: You can use `brew info htop` to see caveats content

Comment: This is helpful for those who installed with macports as well; for me, I don't know why, but `sudo htop` didn't work. `htop` was installed in `/bin`, so I `cd`'d there and ran `chmod 6555 htop && sudo chown root htop`. Now `htop` works fine.

Comment: @AB not anymore, they changed it.

Comment: This solution allows any user to kill any other user's (or root's) processes. Is there a way to allow htop to *read* CPU and MEM without allowing it to modify the system?

Comment: If you want to modify `htop` wherever it's installed, use `chmod 6555 "$(which htop)"`

Answer (score 21):

From my brew info:

```
You can either run the program via `sudo` or set the setuid bit:

  sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local/Cellar/htop-osx/0.8.2.2/bin/htop

  sudo chmod u+s /usr/local/Cellar/htop-osx/0.8.2.2/bin/htop
```

This worked to ensure that I don't need to run htop as sudo

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative for those who don't want to muck with the permissions and still avoid typing `sudo htop` in preference to just `htop`:

1. Install with brew: `brew install htop`
2. Allow `sudo htop` to run without sudo password

   1. Run `sudo visudo` to open the sudoers file in an editor
   2. Add this to the config file: `%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/htop`
   3. Save the file and exit (`:wq` most likely)
3. Add the following alias to your shell rc file (example is for `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`):  `alias htop='sudo htop'`

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this, the location of `htop` has moved, so the correct answer given by @Ivan above can be done using `readlink` and `which` to make sure it always points to the correct `htop` location.

```
sudo chown root:wheel $(readlink -fn $(which htop))
sudo chmod u+s $(readlink -fn $(which htop))
```

Also, for me, `htop` version 3.2.2 gives the same output using this `setuid` version as running with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for the latest versions of htop to function correctly on OS X, it is not sufficient to "bless" htop with `chmod 6555 htop` and `sudo chown htop` - while htop will run, the output will differ between `htop` and `sudo htop`.

Here's a screenshot of the "blessed" htop instance, invoked as `htop`:

[image]

and here's a picture of it running as `sudo htop`:

[image]

As you can see, the non-sudo-invoked `htop` displays significantly less information.

The correct answer was presented by @Sukima; it is unfortunately required to alias `htop` to `sudo htop`. For command line users, typing in the password at the prompt is second nature and I think for most of us it's forgetting to launch `htop` as sudo that is the problem rather than being required to type in the password. I highly advise against allowing `sudo htop` to run without a password prompt, but if you do wish to do so, the best approach is to allow a single, named user to launch htop (and only htop) without a password (though this is a huge vulnerability since htop is powerful and extensible and can run external commands, which means whoever runs htop as sudo can do anything):

```
sudo visudo
# add the line below somewhere in the editor
YOURUSERNAME ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/htop
# save and exit
```