# Alternative to run htop as sudo on OS X?

Tags: macos

To see the CPU and memory usage of processes in `htop` on Mac OS X you need to change the user rights as described in ["htop isn't returning CPU or memory usage!?"](https://superuser.com/a/935695/588611).

`htop` running with root rights is able to stop and kill any process. I don't recommended to use `htop` with superuser rights without any password confirmation.

What is the best alternative with as less rights as possible?

Answer (score -1):

For better system security [`glances`](https://nicolargo.github.io/glances/) i.e. is a better choice for just monitoring the system.

Comment: Can you explain why this is better?

Comment: Cause it does not need root privileges, it is just saver to work without admin rights.